# Imitate a COUNT... GROUP BY in Cloudant (CouchDB)

Tags: group-by, couchdb, aggregate, cloudant

In CloudAnt, I want to get counts of features, grouped by two attributes: topics and councils. After a lot of fiddling, I was able to construct this:

```
// map
function (doc) {
  if (doc.properties && doc.properties.openCouncilDataTopic) {
    var ret = {};
    ret [doc.properties.openCouncilDataTopic] = {};
    ret [doc.properties.openCouncilDataTopic][doc.properties.sourceCouncilId] = 1;

    emit(null, ret);  
  } 
}

// reduce
function (keys, values, rereduce) {

    var ret = values[0];

    function zero(x) { return x ? x : 0 }
    function add(i, topic, id) {
        ret[topic][id] = zero(ret[topic][id]) + values[i][topic][id];
    }
    function countTopic(topic) {
        if (!ret[topic])
            ret[topic] = {};
        Object.keys(values[i][topic]).forEach(add.bind(undefined, i, topic));
    }
    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        Object.keys(values[i]).forEach(countTopic);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way! Cloudant supports "[aggregation over complex keys](https://examples.cloudant.com/simplegeo_places/_design/geo/index.html)"

Instead of manually computing the counts, the `map` function can simply emit keys which are the attributes to group on:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.properties && doc.properties.openCouncilDataTopic) {
    emit([doc.properties.openCouncilDataTopic, doc.properties.sourceCouncilId], 1);  
  } 
}
```

Then we can use the built-in `_count` reduce function.

To call the view, add `group_by=2`, where 2 is the number of attributes to group by. (The default, 0, aggregates everything down to a single number).

This is likely to be much faster than implementing the count in Javascript, too.

One downside is we have less control over the output, which comes out like this:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "key": [
        "childcare-centres",
        "https://data.gov.au/organization/cardinia-shire-council"
      ],
      "value": 22
    },
    ...
}
```